# Solving a system of trigonometric equation embedded inside module for multiple times

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

\begin{align*}
u_{1}&=c_{1}cos(\beta x)+c_{2}sin(\beta x)\nonumber\\
u_{2}&=c_{3}cos(\beta (x-z_{1}))+c_{4}sin(\beta (x-z_{1}))\nonumber\\
u_{3}&=c_{5}cos(\beta (x-z_{2}))+c_{6}sin(\beta (x-z_{2}))\nonumber\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}  
u(x) & = \begin{cases}
                u_{1} & x\leq z_{1} \\
                 u_{2} & z_{1}<x\leq z_{2} \\
                 u_{3} &  x>z_{2} \\ 
                    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
e_{1}&=u_{1}(x=0)\nonumber\\
e_{2}&=\frac{\partial u_{1}(x=1)}{\partial x}\\
e_{3}&=u_{1}(x=z_{1})-u_{2}(x=z_{1})\nonumber\\
e_{4}&=\frac{\partial u_{1}(x=z_{1})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u_{2}(x=z_{1})}{\partial x}+k_{1}u_{1}(x=z_{1})\nonumber\\
e_{5}&=u_{2}(x=z_{2})-u_{3}(x=z_{2})\nonumber\\
e_{6}&=\frac{\partial u_{2}(x=z_{2})}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u_{3}(x=z_{2})}{\partial x}+k_{2}u_{2}(x=z_{2})\nonumber\\
\end{align*}

I have a piecewise function $u$ which depends on six unknown coefficients $c_{i}$,$i=1..6$ and $\beta$. The inputs are $z_{1},z_{2},k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$. The $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ can take two values one $k_{i}\rightarrow 0$ and the other is $k_{i}\rightarrow \infty$, like this four combination is possible. and I need to construct $u$ for the first three values of $\beta$ which can be obtained by solving the matrix constructed using six equation (this is the roots of the determinant of matrix constructed using six equation $e_{i}$). I have written a small module seem like it is not working. Below is my code.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Clear[K1, K2]
L = 1;      
z1 = L/3;
z2 = 0.8;
u1 = c[1] Cos[b x] + c[2] Sin[b x];
u2 = c[3] Cos[b (x - z1)] + c[4] Sin[b (x - z1)];
u3 = c[5] Cos[b (x - z2)] + c[6] Sin[b (x - z2)];
u = Piecewise[{{u1, x <= z1}, {u2, z1 < x <= z2}, {u3, x > z2}}];

e[1] = u1 /. x -> 0;
e[2] = (D[u3, {x, 1}]) /. x -> L;
e[3] = (u1 /. x -> z1) - (u2 /. x -> z1);
e[4] = (D[u1, {x, 1}] /. x -> z1) - (D[u2, {x, 1}] /. x -> z1) + 
   K1 (u2 /. x -> z1);
e[5] = (u2 /. x -> z2) - (u3 /. x -> z2);
e[6] = (D[u2, {x, 1}] /. x -> z2) - (D[u3, {x, 1}] /. x -> z2) + 
   K2 (u3 /. x -> z2);

rodeq = Table[e[i], {i, 1, 6}];
MatrixForm[rodeq];
rodvar = Table[c[i], {i, 1, 6}];
rodR = Normal[CoefficientArrays[rodeq, rodvar][[2]]];
MatrixForm[rodR]
MatrixRank[rodR]
rodP = FullSimplify[Det[rodR]]
```

Comment: That is not a small module. What exactly is not working. Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: I tried hard to minimize the code as possible. But the results I am getting from the code is wrong